# C - how to correctly use malloc'ed array with C getline function?

Tags: c, file, getline

I want to use previously malloc'ed array with a C getline function:

```
ssize_t getline(char **restrict, size_t *restrict, FILE *restrict)
```

The following code gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x400) :

```
FILE *in; if ((in=fopen(inpath, "r+w"))==NULL) exit(1);
char * buf = (char *) malloc (BUFSIZ); // BUFSIZ is constant, equal to 1024
if (getline(&buf, (size_t *)BUFSIZ, in)<0) return 1; // <--- EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

How should I modify the code to make it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing now essentially tells `getline` there's a pointer to the address `1024` and you really want it to dereference it. Pass a real address as the second argument, don't cast an `int` and hope for the best.

```
size_t size = BUFSIZ;
getline(&buf, &size, in);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought the problem is around buffer and went to a wrong way...